# Can this way of comparing numbers of the form a+b sqrt(K) be generalized?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, computer-science, computer-algebra

So I want to make a system for computing with various classes of numbers. One of those is a class of number closed under the standard arithmetic operators ($+$, $-$, $*$ and $/$) along with square roots. This is pretty simple: I can extend any sufficiently nice ordered ring $R$ into $R[X]/(X^2-K)$. How to calculate the standard arithmetic operators on this ring is well-known, and I found a very elegant algorithm for computing the order:

Take $f(x) = x\cdot\!\!\left|x\right|$. Suppose you want to know if $a+b\sqrt{K}<c+d\sqrt{K}$. With simple algebra we can change this question to $a-c<(d-b)\sqrt{K}$. If we apply $f$, we get $f(a-c)<f(d-b)\cdot K$. This reduces the inequality in $R[X]/(X^2-K)$ to an inequality in $R$. Thus, if we take $R$ to be some ring that we already have an algorithm for computing $<$ (such as $\mathbb{Z}$), we have a way of computing $<$ in $R[X]/(X^2-K)$.

This is all well and good. However, this only gives us square roots, and I would like as powerful of a system as possible. Even cube roots seem impossible to work with. Initially, they might seem easy, but one has to remember that members of $R[X]/(X^3-K)$ are of the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{K}+c\sqrt[3]{K}^2$, not $a+b\sqrt[3]{K}$. Thus, the 'easiest' question is this: can this method be extended to work with $n$'th roots? A harder question lies in extending this method to deal with roots of polynomials that are not of the form $x^n-k$, such as the polynomial $x^5-x-1$ (thus letting me compute nicely with real algebraic numbers).

Comment: Also, in case what 'sufficiently nice' means becomes relevant, I can guarantee that any ordered ring that is a subring of an archimedean field is sufficiently nice, and I do not for now need anything more general than that.

Comment: *...this method...*--which method?

Comment: In the second paragraph, I explained a way to compare elements in $R[X]/(X^2-K)$ (when you already have a method of comparing elements in $R$). That is the method I was talking about when I wrote 'this method'.

Comment: I asked essentially the same question some time ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69805/algorithm-to-determine-sign-of-a-polynomial  You may find some useful information in Igor Rivin's answer to that also.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't want $R[X]/(X^2-K)$, because in this ring there is no preferred choice of a square root of $K$. You want a ring that has such a preferred square root, i.e. the positive one. Thus this isn't really about rings and ring extensions, it is about totally ordered rings and extensions of totally ordered rings.

Comment: Do you need to deal with ${\bf R}[X]/(X^2+1)$? and if so, how do you do it?

Comment: Johannes Hahn: I know, but the numbers in $R[X]/(X^2-K)$ can be given an order (the order I described) which 'causes' the square root to be the positive one. Gerry Myerson: No need to deal with negative $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can compute with roots of arbitrary polynomials in a real-closed field. The algorithms are nowhere near as simple to describe, but in one way or another they can be thought of as generalizing the trivial algorithms for computing in $R[\sqrt K]$. See e.g. Yap, [Fundamental problems in algorithmic algebra](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/book/alge/ftpSite/) (in particular §VII), or Basu, Pollack, Roy, [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html) (§10).

Let me sketch some possibilities for the setup specifically mentioned in the question: we have a fixed ordered field $R$ where we know how to compute, an ordered algebraic extension $R[\alpha]$ of $R$, and we want to compute the ordering on elements of $R[\alpha]$; in other words, given a polynomial $f\in R[x]$, determine the sign of $f(\alpha)$.

First, there are several useful ways how to specify $\alpha$. One thing we want is an irreducible (or at least square-free) polynomial $g\in R[\alpha]$ such that $g(\alpha)=0$. Then we need something to uniquely determine $\alpha$ among the roots of $g$ in the real closure $\def\rcl#1{\tilde{#1}^\mathrm{real}}\rcl R$:

- The isolating interval representation consists of $u,v\in R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ such that $\alpha$ is the unique root of $g$ in the interval $(u,v)$ of $\rcl R$. (Such an interval does not necessarily exist if $R$ is nonarchimedean.)
- The sign encoding consists of the sequence of signs of $g'(\alpha),g''(\alpha),\dots,g^{(d)}(\alpha)$, $d=\deg(g)$.
- Generalizing these two cases, we may be given a sequence of polynomials $h_1,\dots,h_k\in R[x]$ such that $\alpha$ is the unique root of $g$ in $\rcl R$ such that $h_1(\alpha),\dots,h_k(\alpha)>0$.

For example, for $\alpha=\sqrt[n]a$, we can take $g(x)=x^n-a$, and the isolating interval $(0,+\infty)$, or the sign encoding $(+,\dots,+)$, or $h_1(x)=x$.

Now, assume we want to determine the sign of $f(\alpha)$:

- If $\alpha$ is given by an isolating interval $(u,v)$, and $f$ is square-free (which we can arrange by first computing its square-free decomposition), we can compute the Sturm sequence $f_0=g$, $f_1=f$, $f_{i+1}=-(f_{i-1}\bmod f_i)$. Then the sign of $f(\alpha)$ is the sign of $(g(v)-g(u))(V(u)-V(v))$, where $V(u)$ is the number of sign changes (ignoring $0$) in the sequence $f_0(u),f_1(u),\dots$.
- If $\alpha$ is given by a sign encoding, or the more general representation with $h_1,\dots,h_k$: we run the BKR algorithm (see Yap, §VII.7–8) with $A=g$, $\overline B=[f,h_1,\dots,h_k]$. This will output all sequences of signs $[s,s_1,\dots,s_k]$ of $\overline B$ on the roots of $g$; one of them will be $[s,+,\dots,+]$, where $s$ is the sign of $f(\alpha)$.

Comment: Do these algorithms include determining positivity/negativity?

Comment: Yes, sure. xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: I'll look into those documents. How about simply computing in $R[\sqrt[n]{K}]$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb Z$, with real root $r$, 
and we wish to compare $f(r)$ to $g(r)$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials over $\mathbb Z$.  Swapping terms with negative coefficients to the other side, we
may assume all coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative integers.
Of course $f(r) = g(r)$ iff $f - g$ is divisible by $p$; let's suppose it isn't.
If $s < r < t$ where $s$ and $t$ are rationals, then $f(r) \le f(t)$ and $g(s) \le g(r)$, so to prove $f(r) < g(r)$ (resp. $f(r) > g(r)$) it suffices to find rationals $s$ and $t$ such that
$f(t) < g(s)$ (resp $f(s) > g(t)$), and if $s$ and $t$ are sufficiently close 
to $r$ one of these must be true.  Suitable sequences $s_n$ and $t_n$ increasing and decreasing to $r$ can be found by successive bisection: given $s_n$ and $t_n$ with $r$ the only root of $p$ in the interval $(s_n, t_n)$, 
consider $x = (s_n + t_n)/2$, use Sturm's theorem to count the number of 
roots of $p$ in the interval $(s_n, x)$, and take either
$s_{n+1} = x$ and $t_{n+1} = t_n$ or $s_{n+1} = s_n$ and $t_{n+1} = x$
according to whether this is $0$ or $1$.